# How are these cross-product summations equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, summation

Trying to determine how the $X_{i+1}$ is no longer applicable by changing summation bounds:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (X_{i} + X_{i+1})(Y_{i+1} - Y_{i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}(Y_{i+1} - Y_{i - 1})$$

Can somebody explain algebraically how this is derived from the bounds?

The source is found [here](http://geomalgorithms.com/a01-_area.html), scroll down to "Polygons, 2D Polygons".

Comment: What are the $X_i$ ? What do you mean by no longer applicable ? There is a term $X_0$ on the left hand side of your identity by not on the right hand side

Comment: @tmaths A polygon has N vertices comprised of (X, Y). So $i = 0$ is the first vertex of a polygon with $X_{0}$; thus $X_{1}$ is the X coordinate of the next vertex. As for no $X_{0}$, it would appear this "goes away" by changing the last term from $Y_{i}$ to $Y_{i - 1}$.

Comment: @tmaths I've added a source link for you.

Comment: @xpaul You had a post, I was replying to it, but you deleted it...

Comment: You copied the formula incorrectly, the first summation should be from $i=0$ to $n-1$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Good catch, however I am still interested in seeing the derivation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a previously deleted answer which was almost correct, which I have fixed and reproduced below:

\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (X_{i} + X_{i+1})(Y_{i+1} - Y_{i})\\
&=&\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}X_{i}(Y_{i+1} - Y_{i})+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} X_{i+1}(Y_{i+1} - Y_{i})\\
&=&\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}X_{i}(Y_{i+1} - Y_{i})+\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}(Y_{i} - Y_{i-1})\\
&=&\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}(Y_{i+1} - Y_{i})+\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}(Y_{i} - Y_{i-1})\\
&=&\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}(Y_{i+1} - Y_{i-1})
\end{eqnarray}
The third equality follows since $X_0(Y_1-Y_0)=X_n(Y_{n+1}-Y_n)$ (as the indices are modulo $n$), so removing the $i=0$ term and adding in the $i=n$ term does not change the sum.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the changes of the second summation term in the second equality from the first equality? Specifically, how does changing the bounds on the summation from $i = 0$, $n - 1$ to $i = 1$, $n$ change the subscript of $X$ and the internals of the parens?

Comment: @pstatix Write out all the summands in $\sum_{i=0}^{3-1} Z_{i+1}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^3 Z_{i}$ and you will see they are the same. Same idea holds when $3$ is replaced with $n$. Let $Z_i = X_i(Y_{i}-Y_{i-1})$.